# "Raised mr sign" not rendered correctly

Tags: unicode

I am looking for a implementation of the "raised mr sign" defined in unicode (version 12.0). I tried to get the character from here:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f16c/browsertest.htm

It should be look like this: 🅬 But all I see is a blank rectangle.

It looks like it is not implemented yet by this character-representation: `&#x1f16c;` in HTML.

I can not find an visual representation of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page says it;

> You need a font that supports this character to even have a hope of
>   seeing it correctly in the browser.

Tested the link on Firefox 69, running on Ubuntu 18 LTS, renders fine.
[image]